# How should I select rows of a pandas dataframe whose entries start with a certain string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Apologies if this is contained in a previous answer but I've read this one: [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) and can't work out how to do what I need to do:

Suppose  have some pandas dataframe X and one of the columns is 'timestamp'. The entries are formatted like `'2010-11-03 09:44:05'`. I want to select just those rows that correspond to a specific *day*, for example, select just those rows for which the actual string in timestamp column *starts with* '2010-11-03'. Is there a neat way to do this? Can I do it with a mask or Boolean indexing? Or should I just write a separate line to peel off the day from each entry and then select the rows? Bear in mind the dataframe is large if it helps.

i.e. I want to write something like

`X.loc[X['timestamp'].startswith('2010-11-03')]`

or

`mask = '2010-11-03' in X["timestamp"]`

but these don't actually make any sense.

Comment: What makes you think it does not make any sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:-

```
X[X['timestamp'].str.startswith('2010-11-03')]
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was missing; thank you